# Turn off vim syntax highlighting inside C++ comments

Tags: c++, c, vim, syntax-highlighting

I recently downloaded vim 8.0. I don't know if I messed something up or a default changed, but in this code...

```
int foo()
{
    // This is a comment containing a "string" and the number 5.
    return 42;
}
```

...the `"string"` and `5` are in a different color. It's the same color as when they appear in normal code.  I've never seen that before.  How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was unusually hard to search for, but the answer is in vim's help files.  It's a feature of the syntax highlighting for C and C++ code that ships with vim.  From `:h ft-c-syntax`:

> A few things in C highlighting are optional.  To enable them assign
>   any value to the respective variable.  Example:
>     `:let c_comment_strings = 1`
>   To disable them use ":unlet".  Example:
>     `:unlet c_comment_strings`

The `c_comment_strings` variable controls the highlighting of strings, characters, and numbers inside of comments. It must have been enabled somewhere in my setup.  If I `:unlet` it, comments are all highlighted in one color again.

Comment: Found it.  `c_comment_strings` is set in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`.  I was sourcing `vimrc_example.vim` which includes the defaults.

Comment: vim has the same annoying behaviour for me but I see no sign that I have c_comment_strings set, and explicitly :unlet'ing it changes nothing. Anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: I found that syntax highlighting had to be reinitialized after setting this variable to make it take effect. Setting the variable in my `.vimrc` and reopening the file worked as expected.

Comment: To try things out, I set the variable and then called `syntax enable` to make it take effect (temporarily).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I understand the self-answering, but I strongly suggest for anybody being serious about using Vim as a C++ coding tool to look into vim [`color_coded`](https://github.com/jeaye/color_coded) plugin. There is no way one can achieve satisfactory colorizing with simple refgexp-based scheme. While not without the issues, this plugin (in my view) is as closest as it gets to doing proper colorizing in Vim.

Comment: I agree with this *opinion* but that is what it is.

Comment: @rici, it is not an opinion. Satisfactory C++ highlighting without proper C++ code parsing is not achievable.